# Puppet/hiera : generate sereval files from one template

Tags: puppet, puppetmaster, hiera, template

I'm running puppet 4 and I would like to generate several config files from the same template with different configurations for each one.

for example :

```
# cat /tmp/a.conf 
test1

# cat /tmp/b.conf 
test2
```

And I need to put all those informations in hiera, so something like that I think :

```
test::clusters:
  - 'a.conf'
    text: 'test1'
  - 'b.conf'
    text: 'test2'
```

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I find how to make it works :

Here is my hiera data/common.yaml :

```
test::paramconf:
  'a':
    text: '1'
  'b':
    text: '2'
```

Here is my module configuration manifests/init.pp :

```
class test ($paramconf){
    create_resources(test::conf, $paramconf)
}

define test::conf (
  String[1] $text,
  String[1] $text2 = $title,
) {
  file { "/tmp/${title}.conf":
    ensure  => file,
    owner   => 'root',
    group   => 'root',
    mode    => '0644',
    content => template('test/test2.erb'),
  }
}
```

The only thing I don't understand is why this is working :

```
test::paramconf:
  'a':
    text: '1'
  'b':
    text: '2'
```

And that doesn't work :

```
test::paramconf:
  - 'a':
    text: '1'
  - 'b':
    text: '2'
```

Comment: The first one creates a hash, the second one is an array of hashes. You see the differences in how puppet's ruby interpreter reads these like so:
first file: 
`ruby -e "require 'yaml'; require 'pp'; require 'json'; hash = YAML.load_file('file.yml'); pp hash"
{"test::paramconf"=>{"a"=>{"text"=>"1"}, "b"=>{"text"=>"2"}}}`

second file:
`ruby -e "require 'yaml'; require 'pp'; require 'json'; hash = YAML.load_file('file1.yml'); pp hash"
{"test::paramconf"=>[{"a"=>nil, "text"=>"1"}, {"b"=>nil, "text"=>"2"}]}`

Answer (score 2):

You need a [defined type](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/reference/lang_defined_types.html)

```
define test::clusters (
  $text = undef
) {

  file { "/tmp/${title}":
    ensure  => $ensure,
    owner   => 'root',
    group   => 'root',
    content => template('my_file/example.erb'),
  }

}
```

in templates/test/clusters

```
<%= @text %>
```

Then you can define a `test::clisters` in a manifest like so:

```
::test::clusters { 'a.conf':
  text => 'test1'
}
```

Or if you still wish to use hiera, you can use [create_resources](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/reference/lang_defined_types.html)

Comment: ok thanks I have this running now :
class test {

        test::conf {'a':
          text=> "test",
        }
}

define test::conf (
  String[1] $text,
  String[1] $text2 = $title,
) {
  file { "/tmp/${title}.conf":
    ensure  => file,
    owner   => 'root',
    group   => 'root',
    mode    => '0644',
    content => template('test/test2.erb'),
  }
}

now I need to make it works with hiera

Comment: If you could accept the answer by selecting the tick, it'd be much appreciated!